# If the Hessian is simply a local quadratic, why can't we approximate it with a spline model?

Tags: optimization, hessian-matrix

The Hessian describes the curvature of the loss landscape that we're optimizing on. In particular, it describes the local quadratic of the loss landscape.

My question is: this seems like we could compute the Hessian much more efficently if we just modelled a local spline model. Why not do that?

Comment: It is not obvious in your reasoning that "sample points along the search process  -> create spline model -> compute hessian", instead of "sample points along the search process  -> compute approximate hessian using BFGS" is necessarily better. However, using things like spline models etc is done a lot in optimization models where you don't have analyical expressions of the objective functions, such as values from simulations etc, and the generation of samples is expensive.

Comment: Interesting. I do see a lot of overlap. Things like trust regions build this local quadratic.

Comment: All quasi-newton methods build approximations of hessian, it is very common.